# Как сделать из multiline textbox двумерный массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, winforms, visual-c++, динамические-массивы

Как сделать из multiline textbox двумерный массив?
[image: Как из этого сделать массив]

Comment: Вероятно [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) ?